# Leave Approval Workflow in SharePoint 2013

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I have a Leave Approval workflow that I am working on and not able to make it work.

Logic is I have two approvers Primary Approver and Approving Manager and when an employee submits a request and puts his Manager as (Primary Approver) and Director(Approving Manager) the email should go to Manager asking for approval and if he Approves it should move on to the Director for further approval. If the Manager rejects it, it should stop and not proceed further and send an email to Requestor(Resource Name') that his/her request is rejected and email is sent to Requester(Resource Name') when everybody approves it.

[image]

Comment: Hi, you said that you were not able to make it work. What are you stuck on so far? You can create this with SharePoint Designer 2013 using a SharePoint 2013 Workflow. Sounds like there might be a Leave Requests SharePoint list for users to submit list items? Workflow can start automatically or manually depending on your requirements.

Comment: @spguy Yes I have already started creating it in Designer, but the logic doesn't seem to be right and throws error so any help on the logic would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the exact answer you are looking for but I did something similar a year or so ago might be helpful.  Basically, you need to do the following:

1. Start a task process and assign manager a task to approve/reject
   the request
2. Based on the outcome 'Transition to Stage'
3. If 'Approved' Go to 2nd Stage, else send a rejection email to the requestor and end the workflow or assign director a task to approve/reject.

Sample Screenshots - Note if Manager information is stored on the AD it probably would be better to access it from the AD

[image]
[image]

Comment: @S Merchant Thank You for sharing your logic it helped me think in that direction and I created a new workflow with the logic attached.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help.  Please do accept the answer.

Comment: @S Merchant I didn't do that because you logic didn't work when I tried to replicate maybe i couldn't understand what some variables were used for but it definitely helped me build a new one so I didn't accept yours. I didn't want to confuse others when they are looking to get an answer from this page until somebody tells me your Logic works and maybe I am wrong. Thanks again though !!

Comment: Oh I thought it worked.  Can you tell me what is the exact issue and what part is not working