# Sharepoint Workflow Claim Form Approval Process - Multi User

Tags: workflow, infopath, designer-workflow, workflow-manager, approval

Dear Sharepoint users,

I'm not sure if this is doable i believe it is but not sure how to execute it.

The workflow is a two staged approval. The first is a group manager approval and then the second is a director approval. The first stage will require approval and a reference code to be assigned (pulls off from another sharepoint list) and what i want is that code to then be forwarded to the director to approve.

The first stage if it gets rejected goes no further, if approved with a code then that will get pushed to a director to approve or reject.

Is that possible? is it two workflows or just one workflow with an if else?

Thank you for taking time out to read this and hopefully helping me :) kudos all x

Comment: Have a look at this. Not exact scenario but same approach. 
 Let me know if you need further details. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215116/leave-approval-workflow-in-sharepoint-2013/215139#215139

Comment: If you are using SharePoint Online / Office 365, have a look at this blog http://www.sharepointing.co.uk/2017/07/02/two-stage-approval-process-using-ms-flow/

Comment: thank you I read a book which helped me with inform approval :) so thank you